# is there a way to restrict creation of specific resource in GCP irrespective of the IAM roles?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, policy, vpc, google-iam

I need to restrict creation of `VPCs`of all the projects irrespective of the `IAM` roles.

I tried the `organisation policies`, I was not able to find any policy which restricts the creation of resources.

Is there any other way I can do restrict creation of `VPCs`?

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible to restrict VPC creation using Organization policies but there's another approach utilizing IAM roles & permissions.**

Have a look at the documentation regarding roles needed to administer all your networks.

The most powerful role is [`roles/compute.networkAdmin`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/job-functions/networking#separate_network_security_teams) which gives you control over every aspect of networking in your project;

> Permissions to create, modify, and delete networking resources, except for firewall rules and SSL certificates. The network admin role allows read-only access to firewall rules, SSL certificates, and instances (to view their ephemeral IP addresses). The network admin role does not allow a user to create, start, stop, or delete instances.

If you want to limit users' permissions assign them a [`roles/compute.networkUser`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/job-functions/networking#separate_network_security_teams) role:

> Provides access to a shared VPC network
>
> Once granted, service owners can use VPC networks and subnets that belong to the host project. For example, a network user can create a VM instance that belongs to a host project network but they cannot delete or create new networks in the host project.

And if you want some examples have a look at this document describing a [IAM roles for Networking-related Job Functions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/job-functions/networking#separate_network_security_teams).

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor ,actually i was expecting to do with org policies rather than IAM roles.so no..

Comment: It's not possible to do it with org policies - I updated my answer.